# Garage Collection not freeing memory after scanning IP range

Tags: c#, memory-management, ip, ping, dispose

Im new to C#, Im trying to make an IP scanner, that can scan multiple networks. I'm building my application from this [code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10190/Implement-a-basic-IP-Scanner-for-a-local-LAN-in-C).

The problem is if i scan an network bigger than a /20 network i get OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program. It takes over 4GB of ram to scan a network bigger than a /20.

From what i can find from google this is due to Visual studio only giving 4gb of virtual memory. That's not really a problem as it will be deployed on a machine with 8GB of ram.

The problem is after i scan a network, visual studio still shows the memory is in use after the scan has completed.

I can see that the garage collector has ran from the diagnostic tool window but it doesn't seem to actually free much memory and it doesn't run after the scan has completed.

here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static CountdownEvent countdown;
        static int upCount = 0;
        static object lockObj = new object();
        const bool resolveNames = true;

        public static void Main()        {

            countdown = new CountdownEvent(1);
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            //using the 8.8.0.0 /16 as an test network to scan
            string ipBase = "8.8.0.";
            ipBase = ipBase.Substring(0, (ipBase.LastIndexOf(".")));

            ipBase = ipBase.Substring(0, (ipBase.LastIndexOf(".") + 1));

            for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
            {
                for (int f = 1; f < 255; f++)
                {
                    string ip = ipBase + i.ToString() + "." + f.ToString();

                    Ping p = new Ping();
                    p.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(p_PingCompleted);
                    countdown.AddCount();
                    // Had to remove the 100ms limit as it would mean i would find less nodes.
                    p.SendAsync(ip, ip); //where i get the exception

                }
            }
            countdown.Signal();
            countdown.Wait();
            sw.Stop();
            TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(sw.ElapsedTicks);
            Console.WriteLine("Took {0} milliseconds. {1} hosts active.", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, upCount);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void p_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string ip = (string)e.UserState;
            //Console.WriteLine("{0}", ip);
            if (e.Reply != null && e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                if (resolveNames)
                {
                    string name;
                    try
                    {
                        IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip);
                        name = hostEntry.HostName;
                    }
                    catch (SocketException ex)
                    {
                        name = "?";
                    }
                    string s = $"{ip} ({name}) is up: ({e.Reply.RoundtripTime} ms)";
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{ip} is up: ({e.Reply.RoundtripTime} ms)");
                }
                lock (lockObj)
                {
                    upCount++;
                }
            }
            else if (e.Reply == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pinging {0} failed. (Null Reply object?)", ip);
            }
            countdown.Signal();
        }


    }
}
```

Why is the memory not freed even after the scan has completed?

Thanks for any help.

---updated---

```
public void pingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            sender.GetType();
            Ping p = ((Ping) sender);
            p.Dispose();
            string ip = (string)e.UserState;
            if (e.Reply != null && e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                lock (lockObj)
                {
                    upCount++;
                }
                if (resolveNames)
                {
                    string name;
                    try
                    {
                        IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip);
                        name = hostEntry.HostName;
                    }
                    catch (SocketException ex)
                    {
                        name = Get_Mac_Address(ip);
                        //name = "?";
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) is up: ({2} ms)", ip, name, e.Reply.RoundtripTime);
                    //writeToFile($"Host {upCount} = {ip} ({name}) is up: ({e.Reply.RoundtripTime} ms)");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} is up: ({1} ms)", ip, e.Reply.RoundtripTime);
                    //writeToFile($"{ip} is up: ({e.Reply.RoundtripTime} ms)");
                }
            }
            else if (e.Reply == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pinging {0} failed. (Null Reply object?)", ip);
                //writeToFile($"Pinging {ip} failed. (Null Reply object?)");
            }
            p.Dispose();
            countdown.Signal();
        }
```

Comment: GC is non deterministic, meaning: it will either run or wont. It frees up memory when it wants to.

Comment: The `Ping` class has a [**`Dispose()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Call it from the `PingCompleted` event handler.

Comment: The amount of RAM is not directly related to OutOfMemoryExceptions. These exceptions can occur if there is not enough contiguous memory to hold an allocation. If you can use an x64 architecture  you will have more virtual memory available.

Comment: But see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/794517/3744182) to [How to avoid Memory Leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/794466/3744182) which points to https://blog.mbcharbonneau.com/2006/11/14/using-the-ping-class-in-net-20-without-memory-leaks/.  This article shows that a `Ping` object must be disposed is a specific, tricky way to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @dbc note that the part about having to call explicitly `IDisposable.Dispose` instead of the `Container.Dispose` method might have been true for .NET 2.0 (I can't really check) but isn't true for .NET 4.0. `Ping` overrides the `Container.Dispose` method, so that shouldn't be an issue. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/NetworkInformation/ping.cs,183

Comment: @KevinGosse - thanks, good to know.

Comment: @rokkerboci it’ll want to before an out of memory error is returned. The .NET GC isn’t all-knowing, but it’ll certainly release unreferenced memory before blowing up an app.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But how exactly do i call the Dispose() in the ping completed event handler. sender i assume is ping but when i cast sender to Ping and call p.dispose() at the end of the method it has no effect. Please see updated code